# Gigya - How can I extend the user's session before it ends?

Tags: session, gigya

So, we are using Gigya as our authentication provider.

How can I extend the user's session before it ends?

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the steps:

- get signatureTimestamp and UIDSignature using accounts.getAccountInfo client side
- send this parameter to a custom webservice
- validate the session using accounts.exchangeUIDSignature
- call https://developers.gigya.com/display/GD/accounts.notifyLogin+REST with the user UID
- return to the client the new cookies

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, Gigya has four session modes: fixed, dynamic/sliding, valid forever and default (until browser close).

The only straightforward way to extend an existing session is with dynamic session. For this, the `sessionExpiration` parameter in global config needs to be sent as `-1`.

When this is sent, you need to create a `gltexp_[site's API key in Gigya]` cookie with the relevant value (either timestamp + UID signature or JWT containing the timestamp etc.), which you can update at any point with a new expiration. Note that if you're sending a JWT, your authentication method with Gigya must be JWT, while if you're not sending one, it only works with the user/secret key combination.

More info on all of the above:
https://help.sap.com/viewer/8b8d6fffe113457094a17701f63e3d6a/GIGYA/en-US/4164ae5a70b21014bbc5a10ce4041860.html